# Word for a part of a book containing introduction and background/state of the art

Tags: publications, research-process, writing-style

I am writing a book (a sort of *research memoir*), and it is structured like this:

- PART I:

  - Chapter 1: Introduction
  - Chapter 2: Background, state of the art, description of research lines...
- PART II: Past research (*)

  - Chapter 3: One research contribution
  - Chapter 4: Another research contribution
- PART III: Present and future research (*)

  - Chapter 5: One future research line
  - Chapter 6: Another future research line

(*) It is not the real title, but this is the idea.

**How would you call PART I? I am thinking of 'Preamble'. Any other idea?**

If I called PART I 'Introduction', then I should change the title of Chapter 1 to... what?

---

EDIT

**Would it make sense removing the first 'PART'?, or would it be too odd? Like this:**

- Chapter 1: Introduction
- Chapter 2: Background, state of the art, description of research lines...
- PART I: Past research (*)

  - Chapter 3: One research contribution
  - Chapter 4: Another research contribution
- PART II: Present and future research (*)

  - Chapter 5: One future research line
  - Chapter 6: Another future research line

(*) It is not the real title, but this is the idea.

Comment: "Preamble" is fine, at least for now. When  you find a publisher you can easily change those titles. Focus on the contents.

Comment: Would something like "PART I: Setting the Stage" be too informal for your purposes?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Yes, 'Setting the stage' would be too informal, maybe. I edited the question and added another possible approach.

Comment: I agree with "preamble". "Prologue" could also work, but it's a bit odd in an academic context to me.

Comment: (1) A "preamble" is not two chapters of a book. It is much shorter.  (2) The introduction should be before any of the parts. (3) If you only have six chapters, you don't need parts.

Answer (score 7):

A possible title for that part is *Preliminaries*.

The second solution is, in my experience as reader, rather unusual.

But do you really need to divide your book in parts? Overall, I find the structure of your table of contents a bit confusing, e.g. why the background material is not covered in the Introduction? Maybe that Introduction is better thought as a *Preface*; and how the present research differs from the state of the art?

Probably, if the book is not too long, I'd avoid the division in parts, and I'd redefine slightly the structure of the chapters.

Comment: I totally agree, except that I think it is fine for background material to not be in the introduction, as the introduction might be long enough already or might contain different kinds of things. I suppose it depends what Background means.